# What’s the difference between equals signs ≈, ≅, and ≃?

Tags: notation

My professors have seemed to use $≅$ and $≈$ pretty interchangeably to indicate that something is nearly equal to something else, and I just became aware of $≃$.

When should we use one of these instead of the other? And, maybe more illustratively, when should one of them *not* be used?

Comment: Context is important. In applied math, $\cong$ it denotes approximately; in Algebra, it denotes isomorphism; in geometry, it denotes congruence...

Comment: Lets add some more.... $\sim$ is "similar to" but it can also appears in equivalence relations.  I suppose similarity is an equivalence relation.  $\equiv$ is "equivalent to" and appears in regularly in modular arithmetic. $\approx$ is aproximately.  $\cong$ is congruence or isomorphism.  And of course $=$ is equality.

Comment: Ask your professors.  Their use is idiomatic and you want to learn their idioms.

Comment: And $\simeq$ denotes homotopic or homotopy equivalent.